# test returns wrong value (but no errors) depending on the presence of spaces around the operator

Tags: bash, string, test, exit-status, syntax

If there are spaces around the operator, `test` returns the correct value of the expression.

But if there are no spaces, it doesn't throw any syntax error and always return true.

```bash
$ test "A" == "A"; echo $?
0 #<-- OK, 0 stands for true
$ test "A" == "B"; echo $?
1 #<-- OK, 1 stands for false
$ test "A"=="A"; echo $?
0 #<-- OK, 0 stands for true
$ test "A"=="B"; echo $? 
0 #<-- ??? should either return 1 (false), or throw a syntax error (exit code > 1)
```

Comment: nitpick, the `==` operator isn't standard, so you might want to use `=` instead for compatibility with all shells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the syntax isn't wrong: `test "A"=="B"` is the same as `test foo`, it is testing a string and since the string isn't empty, it is returns true. This is explained in the `test` section of `man bash`:

> `test` and `[` evaluate conditional  expressions  using a set of
> rules based on the   number of arguments.
>
> - 0 arguments
>
>   The expression is false.
> - 1 argument
>
>   The expression  is  true  if  and
>   only if the argument is not null.

Arguments are defined by whitespace, so since there is no space around the `==`, the entire string `"A"=="B"` is parsed as a single argument.

And here it is in action:

```
$ test foo; echo $?
0
$ test ""; echo $?
1
```

As you can see above, passing an empty string will return false, but passing a non-empty string returns true.